# Nginx won't start. /usr/sbin/nginx and /var/run/nginx.pid don't exist

Tags: linux, bash, nginx

I try to Nginx with `/etc/init.d/nginx start`. It exits with value 0 and otherwise does absolutely nothing because `/usr/sbin/nginx` doesn't exist.

Here is `/etc/init.d/nginx`:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       nginx
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -r /etc/default/nginx ]; then
        . /etc/default/nginx
fi

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# We made the awk expression more precise:
# https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=1060
PID=$(awk -F'[ \t;]+' '/[^#]\<pid/ {print $2}' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
if [ -z "$PID" ]
then
  PID=/var/run/nginx.pid
fi

# Check if the ULIMIT is set in /etc/default/nginx
if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ]; then
  # Set the ulimits
  ulimit $ULIMIT
fi

test_nginx_config() {
                $DAEMON -t $DAEMON_OPTS >/dev/null 2>&1
                retvar=$?
                if [ $retvar -ne 0 ]
                then
                        exit $retvar
                fi
}

start() {
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID \
                        --retry 5 --exec $DAEMON --oknodo -- $DAEMON_OPTS
}

stop() {
                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PID \
                        --retry 5 --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
}

case "$1" in
        start)
                test_nginx_config
                log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
                start
                log_end_msg $?
                ;;

        stop)
                log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
                stop
                log_end_msg $?
                ;;

        restart|force-reload)
                test_nginx_config
                log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
                stop
                sleep 1
                start
                log_end_msg $?
                ;;

        reload)
                test_nginx_config
                log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC configuration" "$NAME"
                start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile $PID \
                        --oknodo --exec $DAEMON
                log_end_msg $?
                ;;

        configtest|testconfig)
                log_daemon_msg "Testing $DESC configuration"
                if test_nginx_config; then
                        log_daemon_msg "$NAME"
                else
                        exit $?
                fi
                log_end_msg $?
                ;;

        status)
                status_of_proc -p $PID "$DAEMON" nginx
                ;;

        *)
                echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest}" >&2
                exit 1
                ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I see that it exits with value 0 because of the `test -x $DAEMON || exit 0` line. If I comment that line out then the script will stop suddenly inside of the `test_nginx_config()` function when it goes to run the daemon (`/usr/sbin/nginx`) which doesn't exist. There is no `/usr/local/nginx/` directory either, for what it's worth.

I'm a total newbie at this stuff so there might be something dumb simple going on but I just need to get this started up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of `which nginx` ?

Comment: Nothing is output to the console when I run `which nginx`.

Comment: Then it's probably because nginx is not installed correctly (it's not in your path). Did you use `apt-get`/`yum`/... or did you install it from the source code ?

Comment: I wasn't the one who installed nginx in the first place. This system was inherited. It's worth noting that I've seen nginx work on this machine before. We needed to reboot the machine and restart nginx and this is where I'm at now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if this is your start up script and nginx used to work with it then, Nginx has been removed by something or someone.